# Remove or Display none static text in html code

Tags: html, css, lightgallery

I want to remove or set css property as `display:none` for the text element which has no html element or has no id or class attribute.
[image]
Please check image for reference.

Comment: That's inside the div tag set attribute of the div tag

Comment: Or you can also add a apan tag around it and set it's attribute

Comment: You could write a function in javascript that surrounds these texts with span tags and assigns random generated values at clients browser and then you can set some logic to set the attributes using setAttribute method of set style using element.style.display="none" or if you just want to remove that text useparent div .innerText =""

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee yes but this text what do I call? lets say parent div = #lg-counter then what will be the code I use?

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee I cannot add span around it or anything.. its auto-generated code from light gallery library.

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee Give me javascript code or so... I need solution.. I have tried alot of things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `font-size: 0` trick.

```css
div {
  font-size: 0;
}

div * {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>text 1</span>
  unwanted text
  <span>text 2</span>
</div>
```